# Unable to mask spatial object even after transforming the CRS of the shapefile to match the CRS of the raster

Tags: r, geospatial, mask, shapefile, terra

I'm trying to mask a raster using a shapefile in R, specifically using the `terra` package. However, I'm encountering an issue where the output after masking is all `NaN` values. I've followed the documentation and made sure that the coordinate reference systems (CRS) of both the raster and shapefile match, but the problem persists.

By looking at the two plots, I believe the cause of the problem is that the extension of the raster is incorrect. The latitude should start at -180 up to 180.  The raster and shapefiles I am using can be obtain in the following [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1E7Tr9qYFHyjFINaIFNoyZSLMW0V3y-8a?usp=sharing).

```
# ---- NOAA global temperature data ----
# Load the terra package
if (!require(terra)) install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')

# Load NOAA global temperature data
tmax_2018 <- rast("data/temperature/tmax.2018.nc")

tmax_2018_Jan1 <- tmax_2018[[1]]
```

```
> tmax_2018_Jan1
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 360, 720, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 360, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source      : tmax.2018.nc 
varname     : tmax (Daily Maximum Temperature) 
name        : tmax_1 
unit        :   degC 
time        : 2018-01-01 UTC
```

[image]

```
# ---- Ecuador shapefile ----
# Load sf package
if (!require("sf")) install.packages("sf")

# Load Ecuador shapefiles
ecuador_shp <- st_read('data/ecu_shapefiles/ECU_adm1.shp')
ecuador_shp <- st_simplify(ecuador_shp, preserveTopology = TRUE, dTolerance = 100)

# Change the CRS to match the SpatRaster's CRS
ecuador_shp <- st_transform(ecuador_shp, crs(tmax_2018_Jan1))

# Transforming sf class to SpatVector class from terra
ecuador_shp <- vect(ecuador_shp)
```

```
> ecuador_shp
 class       : SpatVector 
 geometry    : polygons 
 dimensions  : 24, 9  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : -92.00854, -75.20007, -5.017001, 1.681093  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
 names       :  ID_0   ISO  NAME_0  ID_1  NAME_1    TYPE_1 ENGTYPE_1 NL_NAME_1 VARNAME_1
 type        : <num> <chr>   <chr> <num>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>
 values      :    68   ECU Ecuador     1   Azuay Provincia  Province        NA        NA
                  68   ECU Ecuador     2 Bolivar Provincia  Province        NA        NA
                  68   ECU Ecuador     3   Cañar Provincia  Province        NA        NA
```

[image]

```
# ---- Masking ----
tmax_2018_Jan1_ecu <- terra::mask(tmax_2018_Jan1, ecuador_shp)
plot(tmax_2018_Jan1) # Shows an empty plot.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is (first) a simplified and condensed version of margusl's answer.

```
library(terra)
tmax_2018 <- rast("tmax.2018.nc")
tmax_2018 <- rotate(tmax_2018)

ecu <- vect('ecu_shapefiles/ECU_adm1.shp')
tmax_2018_ecu <- crop(tmax_2018, ecu, mask=TRUE)

plot(tmax_2018_ecu, 1)
lines(ecu)
```

If you do not want to rotate the raster data, you could shift the vector data instead.

```
library(terra)
tmax_2018 <- rast("tmax.2018.nc")

ecu <- vect('ecu_shapefiles/ECU_adm1.shp')
secu <- shift(secu, 360)
tmax_2018_secu <- crop(tmax_2018, secu, mask=TRUE)

plot(tmax_2018_secu, 1)
lines(secu)
```

And you could then shift the result. That could be more efficient if that is an issue.

```
tmax <- shift(tmax_2018_secu, -360)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. And thank you very much for creating this package.

Answer (score 2):

Try rotating it first.

> *rotate {terra}  -  Rotate data along longitude*
> Rotate a SpatRaster that has longitude coordinates from 0 to 360, to standard coordinates between -180 and 180 degrees (or vice-versa). Longitude between 0 and 360 is frequently used in global climate models.

And you may want to crop by shp as well.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.23

# load, check extent
tmax_2018 <- rast("tmax.2018.nc")
ext(tmax_2018)
#> SpatExtent : 0, 360, -90, 90 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

# rotate, check extent
tmax_2018_r <- rotate(tmax_2018)
ext(tmax_2018_r)
#> SpatExtent : -180, 180, -90, 90 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
plot(tmax_2018[[1]])
plot(tmax_2018_r[[1]])
```

[image]

```r
ecuador_shp <- read_sf('ecu_shapefiles/ECU_adm1.shp')
ecuador_shp <- st_simplify(ecuador_shp, preserveTopology = TRUE, dTolerance = 100)

tmax_2018_crop <- crop(tmax_2018_r, ecuador_shp)
plot(tmax_2018_crop[[1]])
plot(ecuador_shp$geometry, add = TRUE)

tmax_2018_masked <- mask(tmax_2018_crop, ecuador_shp)
plot(tmax_2018_masked[[1]])
plot(ecuador_shp$geometry, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
tmax_2018_masked
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 13, 34, 365  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#> extent      : -92, -75, -5, 1.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> names       :    tmax_1,   tmax_2,   tmax_3,   tmax_4,   tmax_5,   tmax_6, ... 
#> min values  :  9.768158, 17.85175, 15.38072, 17.51550, 13.29921, 13.41261, ... 
#> max values  : 33.109238, 34.98264, 35.73123, 33.20931, 33.43045, 33.31937, ... 
#> time        : 2018-01-01 to 2018-12-31 UTC
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Two follow up questions. 1) You didn't use the `st_transform` function. I guess because they originally came with the same CRS just different longitude coordinates. 2) You didn't transform the sf class shapefile to SpatVector class from terra. Isn't this necessary?

Comment: Yes, both use the same WGS84 crs and terra indeed supports sf objects in number of raster-vector interaction functions. If you'd address those questions to Robert here, you'd have a chance to get a much better explanation -- right from the source ;)